# Java applications prevent server restart after JRE update

Tags: windows, java

I have a problem after JRE update.

If I have a launched Java application and initiate system restart - Windows fails to automatically stop this Java application and I get following message:
*"This program is preventing Windows from restarting".*
If I press cancel, then I could see that Java application that prevents restart hangs.
This issue affects both my Java applications and such applications as jconsole.

Before JRE update everything works fine on **JRE 1.6.0_26**.
I first faced this problem on **JRE 1.6.0_36**. But it also happens on 1.6.0_39.

P.S: I have Windows Server 2008 R2 Interprise

Have anyone had same problem or can suggest what to do in this situation?
Thanks.

**Update:**
I have implemented following addhook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
public void run() {
logger.log("SHUTDOWN - BEGIN");
((Window) view).setVisible(false);
logger.log("SHUTDOWN - Visible");
((Window) view).dispose();
logger.log("SHUTDOWN - Dispose");
System.exit(0);
}
});
```

After that applications with such addhook closes normally on system restart, but  I figured out that if we just close application (by pressing exit or "x") Java VM not terminated (we can see javaw process in taskmgr).

From log file I could see that program never leaves dispose() function. In case if I comment dispose() and leave only System.exit(0) Java VM still not able to terminate.

**Update 2:**
Ticket has been created for this issue. And we received following reply from **Oracle: "Problem reproduced and confirmed."**

Comment: This happens for all Java applications or just some of them?

Comment: As I mentioned before this happens with all tested apps (our and 3d party)

Comment: Did you look what your dispose method is doing? it may give some clue

Comment: It's just a standart java Window.dispose method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/pbp1.1.2/jsr217/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29

Comment: I think no need to call `System.exit()` again in your Shutdown hook. Just dispose window and return from `run()`.

Comment: Program freezes in Window dispose... 
logger.log("SHUTDOWN - Dispose");
never appears in log.
Without System.exit javaw not terminated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This issue fixed by Oracle**. Fix will be included in the upcoming version of JRE (1.6.0_42?).

As a **workaround** for **your** application you can use addhook. Something like this:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    ((Window) view).setVisible(false);
    Runtime.halt(0);
    }
    });
```

You should use **Runtime.halt(0)** instead of System.exit(0), because Java Machine refuses to stop after System.exit(0) in current version of JRE.

Comment: I don't suppose you have the bug ID for this? I've run into a similar issue and I'd like to look through the bug to check it matches, but I can't find it on bugs.java.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

matts, This happens for all Java applications, it has been tested with a Server with just 2008 OS and JRE 6U37 on. If we start the Java Control Panel and then try and restart the Server we get the Windows message.

If the App is minimised, we don't get the message.

Message "This program is preventing Windows from restarting"

We get the option to "Force restart" or "Cancel" if you take the Cancel option, the Java Control Panel hangs and the javaw.exe process is running at 25% cpu, this is on a quad processor server, so I assume on a single processor this would be running at 100% cpu.

Oliver

Comment: Looks like solution with minimizing works for our apps but still have no idea what to do with third party.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of few things:

1) Do you have a shutdownhook() implemented, possibly trying to do something when it gets a QUIT signal from OS?

2) Do a thread dump (ctrl + break for windows- pls google?) when your application hangs and check what is happening inside. You should get some clue.

3) Non-daemon threads, if any, still active in the java application may prevent JVM to exit too.

Comment: I implemented addhook and this works (it's possible only with our apps of course), but introduces new problem. Look at the updates in my post.

Comment: Also take a look at halt() API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt(int)

Comment: I've tested Runtime.halt() in addhook with test application and looks like it works now. Now I'll try to do the same with real app.